# Getting the logical column letters

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I need to get the letters of logical column that I have created in my excel sheet.

When I click on a cell ,suppose H7, that has data 23, I am able to get Te excel column H, but for some business purpose I want A, that is the letter in 5th row corresponding to a cell that is selected.If suppose it is 56, I want B.

Image 2 shows why I want B instead of excel column I,it is because if I insert a column my excel column letter will change but the numbers corresponding to the logical column letter in B wil remain in B only.
I am able to get the excel column letters using the code:

```
Public Function ColumnLetters(rInput As Range) As String
ColumnLetters = Split(rInput.Address, "$") (1)
End Function
```

If the column letter extracted is H, I need the value that is in 5th row just below it that is A and so on.For I it's B, and so on.

I have done this so that inserting additional columns ,excel column letters will change but it won't change my logical column letters.

Can someone please help, please?[image: image1][image: image2]

Comment: Can you come up with an example, where it does not change your logical column letters?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve???

Comment: I want to refer my target cell column.so the data in I can always be referred by the logical column letter in 5th row corresponding to I.Even if I insert column before I and I become J in excel column, my Letter B I'm 5th row will be intact.That is why am trying to fetch the column letter I have created in 5th row and not excel column letter

Comment: I wanted to add a pic so you could get it better and try once but am new to stack over flow and due to lack of badges ,i cant add pic :(

Comment: put  a link of the pic to the comments. Or edit your post and put a link of the pic there. Or put the pic in your post.

Comment: Let me understand. You are interested in the 5th row of a specific column, say **F**, even if you add a column (say beween B and C such that your **F** would become **G**). If this is the case, you can simply **NAME** the column (typing a name in the upper leftmost field). You could also name the first cell of your column and then calculate the address of the desired cell in that column (indirect-referencing). From either **NAME**, you could also extract its letter or column number.

Comment: @FDavidov I think you are getting it. I need to extract the letter of 5th row by Vba code. The code that I have written above, can it be modified in a way that i get the 5th row column letter? Offset or something like that?

Comment: You are making things difficult to understand. The letter of the fifth column will **ALWAYS** be **E**. You are not talking about the fifth column, but about the INITIAL fifth column that may become a different one, right? If that is the case, my previous comment gives you a solution.

Comment: Additionally, you could use a notation like `Ra:Cb` (meaning row `a` column `b`).

Comment: something like `=CHAR(COLUMN()+60)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As FDavidov has said - you can use named ranges to achieve this if we're understanding your question correctly.

In the example shown below I have highlighted column A and typed the name `RefThisColumn` in the `Name Box` (red square).  I have also selected just cell A1 and typed `RefThisCell` in the `Name Box`.

I can then use these named ranges in VBA without having to update references.
After inserting columns to move my named ranges into column E (green square) I ran the exact same code and got the exact same result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just want to convert a column number to a letter, right?

On your Vba code, use `Chr()`. This will convert a number you input to a character.

If you put `Chr(65)` it will return "A". You just need to add your calculations now to reach the letter you want.

I didn't understand what exactly you want, but as an example, lets say `col` is your column number variable.

The `Chr(64+col)` would return A for column 1.

However if you wanted to return A for column 5, you would tweak it like `Chr(60+col)`

Comment: I have added images and explanation.Please refer to my edited question.I hope you get it now. :(

Answer (score 0):

Set the H5 formula to this:

```
=MID(ADDRESS(ROW(H5),COLUMN(H5)-COLUMN($H5)+1),2,LEN(ADDRESS(ROW(H5),COLUMN(H5)-COLUMN($H5)+1))-3)
```

Then extend this formula across the remaining columns.

This takes the row and column of the current cell, generates the address in the format `$H$5`, and extracts the H from it. But it offsets all the columns relative to column H, so H becomes A, I becomes B, etc.

Some of the other solutions are fine if you just want A-Z but this works for more than 26 columns, giving you AA in the 27th, if that's what you want.